# expected at least 1 argument, got 0

Tags: robotframework

I installed robot framework yesterday and trying to run a test file.Below is my test file, while i try to run the file using  robot -d tests/Amazon.robot , i am getting a error as

```
[Error] Expected at least 1 argument,got 0.
```

can someone please help me.

[image]

Comment: When writing a question you want people to take out time of their day to answer them. It should be as easy for _them_ to help you. Using screenshots of your code is not helping the people answering your question faster, but is more likely only saving you a little bit of time while frustrating those _willing_ to answer. For more tips like this read the [help] and [ask] sections.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify where to look for tests and you are using `-d` incorrectly.

Most likely you need command `robot tests/Amazon.robot`

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Your test did not run at all. Robot is expecting a test file, but you provided it as the directory location for outputs. You will then have another error, because it is a file not a directory.

Comment: But robot on terminal should accept the parameters like -d  or -t as well in the correct order. why           >robot -d ADire  -t file.robot       create the same error as outlined here in the OP question?

Comment: @Michelle, Usage example of robot is the following: `robot [options] paths`. Your example could be translated as " run test named file.robot and put results in ADire directory", but you did not specify where to search for tests. If you want to run all tests from file.robot you should remove `-t` so it would look like `robot -d ADire file.robot`

Answer (score 2):

The problem looks like in the usage of the `Sleep` keyword - you want to pass the argument "3" to it, but did not put two or more spaces b/n them.

---

With problems like this, check the generated log.html file - the failure will be in the record for the specific keyword, helping you pinpoint which line is the error one.